# what is the differnce between heroku and openshift?

Tags: heroku, openshift

i'd like to know what is the difference between heroku and openshift, for now i'm going to use the free package for my blog, i've noticed the openshift has more supported techs.

what about the limitation of each one of them

Answer (score 1):

Both Heroku and OpenShift are open platforms.

Neither one has any 'lock in', so you can easily move your app in and out of each service with minimal hassle. They all use standard open source tools, and work as expected.

The main difference is ease of use. Heroku is quite a bit simpler to use that OpenShift. Heroku basically handles 100% of your application deployment. You basically write your code in a git repo, then say 'git push heroku master' and your code will magically be running on Heroku.

OpenShift, on the other hand, requires more work. It's not uncommon to setup and tweak your own web servers, infrastructure components, etc.

The honest answer is that you can't really go wrong either way. I've been using Heroku for years and love for both big and small apps, but OpenShift is fine as well.